# Blackberry Multiple OS version compatibility issue

Tags: blackberry, java-me, preprocessor, compatibility

I have developed a chat application on BlackBerry OS 5.0 but my client wants me to make it portable to all the platforms from 4.5 to 5.0 and above.
I have tried using preprocessor directives to compile the OS compatible classes at run time, but I haven't succeeded in it yet. I doubt the way I'm using preprocessors. so I'm putting up an example here:

```
//#ifdef JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE
/*
//#endif

//some code

//#ifdef JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE
*/
//#endif


//#ifndef JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE
/*
//#endif

//Alternative of code used above

//#ifndef JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE
*/
//#endif
```

this is the way I'm doing it for the particular part of the code. The logic here is to use first code if OS version is 4.6 and above...and to use the second code if OS version is below 4.6....

But the code under preprocessors doesn't seem to compile in either of the case.

**Note:** I have put "//#preprocess" at the start of the code and defined the preprocessors in my application descriptor xml file, but still no luck. Also is there any other solution to handling compatibility between BBOS versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are placing the code outside the statements. ifdef and ifndef open the statements, endif closes the statement. You can also use #else as you only have two cases.

```
//#ifdef JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE

System.out.println("JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE");

//#else

System.out.println("NOT JDE_4_6_0_AND_ABOVE");

//#endif
```

Cheers

Ray

Comment: The code wasn't formatted well before so it may have been hard to see, but user856065 is using the preprocessor to add/remove comment blocks.

Comment: @Michael: I have seen some tutorial websites suggest doing it that way, and I have not had much luck with that approach, either.  I use Ray's approach of putting the code inside the #if blocks, and that works fine for me.

Comment: Doh! I just clicked. If the original code was the original code and not just a result of cut'n'paste then it would not have worked because the comment openers/closers cannot be on the same lines as //#ifdef //#endif (@Michael this might be one time cleaning up code broke the question:)